# __getattribute__ infinite recursion error keeps happening even with "return object.__getattribute__(self, item)"

Tags: python, methods, getattribute, python-3.10

I keep on getting the `__getattribute__` recursion error, even though ive implemented `return object.__getattribute__(self, item)` at the end of the method? Ive tried everything that I could find on the internet but nothing seems to work. I have a feeling that it has to do something with the `Player` class inheriting `pygame.sprite.Sprite`? (I have ideas that use the `__getattribute__` method, so im just testing it out right now)

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (K_a, K_w, K_d, K_s, KEYDOWN, K_ESCAPE, QUIT)


def update_velocity(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        self = args[0]
        last_pos = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

        func(*args)

        # update velocity after method moves sprite
        self.x_velocity = self.rect.x - last_pos[0]
        self.y_velocity = self.rect.y - last_pos[1]

    return wrapper


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.y_velocity = 0
        self.x_velocity = 0
        self.last_pos = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        self.current_pos = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

    @update_velocity
    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_w]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_s]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):  # error
        print(self.x)

        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
```

Comment: `print(self.x)`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica overlooked that mistake but even if i do something like `self.x_velocity` the error still happens?

Comment: You are attempting to *get an attribute* on that line. What do you think happens when you try to *get an attribute*?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It calls `__getattribute__` again? but from my understanding shouldnt the `return object.__getattribute__...` prevent that?